# passing non string parameter from python to Matlab

Tags: python

I am able to pass string(path) parameter to matlab script from python on Win 7 machine (and script runs successfully in **new matlab command window)** as:

```
matlab_cmd_string = MatlabExePth+ " -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -logfile   FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log -minimize -r "
mat_file = "tst_script"
tstPth = 'C\\SVN\\Matlabcode\\tst1'
mat_cmd = matlab_cmd_string + "\"" + mat_file + "("+ "\'" +  tstPth + "\'" + ")" + ", exit\""
```

so that above  evalutes to

> "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop
>   -wait -logfile FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log -minimize -r "tst_script('C\SVN\Matlabcode\tst1'), exit"

However, now, i need to pass a List (which becomes matlab cell array) as argument ,so that Matlab be called as

> tst_script1(Python_list)

However,  what should be passed as argument in python is the list values ,
and not something like

> "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -logfile FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log -minimize -r "tst_script1('Python_list'), exit"

in which *Python_list* is taken as a string.

How do I do that?
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this should work for you.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
matlab_cmd_string = MatlabExePth+ " -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -logfile   FileIoReg_MatlabRemoteRun.log -minimize -r "
mat_file = "tst_script"
tstPth = 'C\\SVN\\Matlabcode\\tst1'
listToBePassed = str(a)
mat_cmd = matlab_cmd_string + '\"' + mat_file + '(' + listToBePassed + ')' + ', exit\"'
```